# CMake cannot find zita-convolver4

Tags: cmake

I am trying to compile jconvolver, which depends on zita-convolver v. 4, using Kubuntu 18.04 LTS, KDevelop v. 5.2.1, gcc v. 7.5.0, CMake v. 3.10.2. However, as far as I can tell there is no deb-package for zita-convolver4. Although there is one marked for testing (https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/zita-convolver), it does not seem to be usable yet.

I have tried to compile zita-convolver4 from sources, but I end up with a linking error:

```
CMakeFiles/myproj.dir/jconvolver-1.0.3/source/zita-convolver.cc.o: In function `calloc_real(unsigned int)':
/home/me/projects/myproj/jconvolver-1.0.3/source/zita-convolver.cc:47: undefined reference to `fftwf_alloc_real'
CMakeFiles/myproj.dir/jconvolver-1.0.3/source/zita-convolver.cc.o: In function `calloc_complex(unsigned int)':
/home/me/projects/myproj/jconvolver-1.0.3/source/zita-convolver.cc:55: undefined reference to `fftwf_alloc_complex'
```

etc, etc.

I do have libfftw3-3 and libfftw3-dev installed, and in CMakeLists.txt I have:

```
    find_package(Qt5Charts)
    find_package(jack)
    find_package(SndFile)
    find_package(libfftw3)
    target_link_libraries(myproj Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Charts jack sndfile         fftw3)
```

The problem seems to be that the linker does not find the fftw3 library. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "The problem seems to be that the linker does not find the fftw3 library." - No, would the linker does not find library specified in the command line, it would emit **another** error message. The "undefined reference" error means that the linker has successfully processed all parameters passed to it and has checked all libraries, specified by these parameters, but none of them contains the required function (`fftwf_alloc_real` in your case). You may check which parameters are **actually** passed to the linker with `make VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: I can compile zita-convolver:
$ sudo make install
Looking into /usr/local/lib64/ I have:
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    26 april 18 20:58 libzita-convolver.so -> libzita-convolver.so.4.0.3*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 34208 april 18 20:58 libzita-convolver.so.4.0.3*
Also, my program compiles, but when running it yields:
 error while loading shared libraries: libzita-convolver.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
*** Failure: Exit code 127 ***
I have been playing with 
load_library(zita-convolver) 
in CMakeLists.txt, but maybe I am use the wrong syntax?

Comment: So you need to create symlink `libzita-convolver.so.4` pointed to the same `libzita-convolver.so.4.0.3`.